# When I press the first button, the first modal works. When I press the second button, the second modal works

Tags: javascript, html

I have two grids, and in each grid I have a button that I would like to have its own unique modal. Whenever I try using Bootstrap's modals' however, I am only getting the first button's data to show up, even though I may be clicking on a different button that should display a different modal.

```
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';
        
export default function myApp() {
    return(
        <div>
            <button className="mybutton" onClick={handleOpen}>Download</button>
            <Modal
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
            >
                <Box sx={style}>
                    <Typography id="my-modal" variant="h6" component="h2">
                        Download
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography id="my-modal" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                        Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.
                    </Typography>
                </Box>
            </Modal>
     
            <button className="mybutton" onClick={handleOpen}>Download</button>
            <Modal
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
            >
                <Box sx={style}>
                    <Typography id="my-modal" variant="h6" component="h2">
                        Download here
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography id="my-modal" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                        <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/145444.jpg"/>
                    </Typography>
                </Box>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: please look at your post ... using formatting unnecessarily just makes a mess

Comment: The problem is that when I press the first button it shows the contents of the first modal, when I press the second button it shows the contents of the second modal

Comment: that is a description of observed behavior ... it is not a description of a problem ... that's like saying `the problem is that my fence is painted blue` ... what were you expecting to happen?

Comment: When I press the first button, it shows both the first modal and the second modal. I want the first button to be assigned to the first modal, the second button to be assigned to the second modal

Comment: now you are contradicting what you said in the title of your post and in a previous comment ... please update your post with a clear description of desired behavior and a clear description of observed behavior

Comment: When I press the first button, the contents of the second second modal are shown. I want the first modal to be displayed when I press the first button.

Comment: please add that information to your question at the top of this page ... use the `edit` button ... make your question clearly understandable